# change in value after casting int to uintptr_t

Tags: c, multithreading, operating-system

As you can see, when I cast `int` to `void*` and then cast it back to `int`, the value is not the same, and I encounter a segmentation fault. What is the problem with this? I also tried `int j = *(int*)i` and it fails, too.

```
void* run(void* i)
{   
    // some code

    uintptr_t j = (intptr_t)(void*)i;
    
    // some code
}

int main()
{
    // some code

    for (int i = 0; i < THREADS; i++)
    {
        void *pointer = &i;
        pthread_create(&threads[i], NULL, run, pointer);
    }
    
    // some code
}
```

Comment: You’re taking a pointer to a local. The life time of that local ends before you dereference it -> undefined behaviour.

Comment: @MikeVine There is no dereference as far as I can tell...

Comment: @EugeneSh Yeah you’re right. It looks like op _should_ be dereferencing it for the code to make any sense. So I’ll leave my comment in although it’s wrong.

Comment: @EugeneSh. The code is far from a [mcve]. OP is showing the dereference in the question text.

Comment: @EugeneSh. why am I getting negative score everytime I ask a question

Comment: @Elitheria Why are you asking me ? :)  IMO the question is OK.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> when I cast `int` to `void*` ...

You are not actually doing that.  Your `run()` function is expecting you to cast the *value* of `i` to a `void*`, but your `main()` loop is instead assigning the *address* of `i` to a `void*`.  Big difference.

The reason why `int j = *(int*)i` fails (although it is syntactically correct when using `void *pointer = &i;`) is because you are making all of the threads act on a single `int` variable in memory. That `int` is changing value on each loop iteration in `main()`, without telling the threads that it is changing.  And worse, the lifetime of that `int` ends as soon as the loop ends, leaving each thread with a dangling pointer.

If you want each thread to act on its own `int` value, you need to pass around the *value* of `i`, not the *address* of `i`, eg:

```
void* run(void* arg)
{   
    // some code

    int j = (int)(intptr_t)arg;
    
    // some code
}

int main()
{
    // some code

    for (int i = 0; i < THREADS; i++)
    {
        void *pointer = (void*)(intptr_t)i;
        pthread_create(&threads[i], NULL, run, pointer);
    }
    
    // some code

    for (int i = 0; i < THREADS; i++)
        pthread_join(&threads[i], NULL);

    // some code
}
```

Alternatively, allocate a separate `int` for each thread, and then pass the *address* of each thread's `int`, eg:

```
void* run(void* arg)
{   
    // some code

    int j = *(int*)arg;

    // some code
}

int main()
{
    // some code

    int arr[THREADS];

    for (int i = 0; i < THREADS; i++)
    {
        arr[i] = i;
        void *pointer = &arr[i];
        pthread_create(&threads[i], NULL, run, pointer);
    }
    
    // some code

    for (int i = 0; i < THREADS; i++)
        pthread_join(&threads[i], NULL);

    // some code
}
```

Comment: So the right way would be something like `void *pointer = (void*)(uintptr_t)i;`

Comment: It should be the other way around. You have stated this as if the call is incorrect and the called routine is correct. Thread data can be passed directly in a pointer value in certain circumstances, but that is generally bad practice. Instead, we should regard the call as correct: Thread data is usually passed as a pointer to the data, using type pointer to `void`. Then the called routine should convert that pointer to a pointer to the appropriate type and use it to access the data. And then OP ought to be using different objects for each thread, guaranteeing sufficient lifetime for each.